# Defun inside let with lexical binding gives byte-compile warning "the function is not known to be defined"

Tags: byte-compilation, lexical-scoping, defun, lexical-binding

I want to get the effect of a static variable by using `defun` inside of `let` with lexical binding to create a closure. However, when byte-compiling the file, I get a warning. Am I doing something wrong, or if not, is there a way to suppress this warning?

I've created an MCVE:

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(let ((count 0))
  (defun increase-count ()
    (interactive)
    (setq count (1+ count))
    (message "Count is: %d" count))

  ;; The warning happens here.
  (increase-count))
```

The code works as expected: the function `increase-count` prints out "Count is: n" where n increases each time it is called. However, when byte-compiling this file, I get the following warning:

```
In end of data:
mcve.el:11:1:Warning: the function ‘increase-count’ is not known to be
    defined.
```

It seems to me that `increase-count` should always be defined before it is called at the end of the let-block. Is this not the case?

Comment: `defun` does not do what you think it does, it always creates a top-level definition. Elisp is after all not Scheme...

Comment: I'm aware that it creates a top-level definition; that's what I want. I just want that top level definition to be a closure. It seems to be working the way I want, except for this byte-compilation warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The byte-compiler's way to decide whether a function will be defined or not is very "naive" and gets fooled even in your "obvious" case.
But you can write it in a way that lets the compiler understand what happens:

```
(defalias 'increase-count
  (let ((count 0))
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (setq count (1+ count))
      (message "Count is: %d" count))))
```

Of course, even better would be to improve the byte-compiler's logic: patches welcome for that.

Answer (score 6):

To suppress the byte-compiler warning, try adding this before your code, starting in column 0 (leftmost):

```
(declare-function increase-count "your-file-name.el")
```

`C-h f declare-function` tells you:

> **`declare-function`** is a Lisp macro in `subr.el`.
>
> `(declare-function FN FILE &optional ARGLIST FILEONLY)`
>
> Tell the byte-compiler that function `FN` is defined, in `FILE`.
>   The `FILE` argument is not used by the byte-compiler, but by the
>   `check-declare` package, which checks that FILE contains a
>   definition for `FN`.
>
> `FILE` can be either a Lisp file (in which case the `".el"`
>   extension is optional), or a C file.  C files are expanded
>   relative to the Emacs `"src/"` directory.  Lisp files are
>   searched for using `locate-library`, and if that fails they are
>   expanded relative to the location of the file containing the
>   declaration.  A `FILE` with an `"ext:"` prefix is an external file.
>   `check-declare` will check such files if they are found, and skip
>   them without error if they are not.
>
> Optional `ARGLIST` specifies `FN`’s arguments, or is `t` to not specify
>   `FN`’s arguments.  An omitted `ARGLIST` defaults to `t`, not `nil`: a `nil`
>   `ARGLIST` specifies an empty argument list, and an explicit `t`
>   `ARGLIST` is a placeholder that allows supplying a later arg.
>
> Optional `FILEONLY` non-`nil` means that `check-declare` will check
>   only that `FILE` exists, not that it defines `FN`.  This is intended
>   for function definitions that `check-declare` does not recognize,
>   e.g., `defstruct`.
>
> Note that for the purposes of `check-declare`, this statement
>   must be the first non-whitespace on a line.
>
> For more information, see Info node [**`(elisp)Declaring Functions`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Declaring-Functions.html).

Comment: Is a non-nil `FILEONLY` argument necessary for the case at hand? BTW, I would have given the same answer;-).

Comment: @Tobias: `FILEONLY` didn't seem to be needed here, for me. Which would seem to indicate that `check-declare` recognizes the `f` and `g` defuns.

Comment: @Drew, I think that last comment about `f` and `g` only makes sense in the context of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/39439 ?

Comment: @phils: Yes, I meant to say this: `FILEONLY` didn't seem to be needed here, for me. Which would seem to indicate that `check-declare` recognizes the `increase-count` defun. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I believe placing the definition in question within `eval-and-compile` would also **superficially** achieve the same result as in Stefan's [correct answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29862/15748):

```el
(eval-and-compile
  (let ((count 0))
    (defun increase-count ()
      (interactive)
      (setq count (1+ count))
      (message "Count is: %d" count))))
```

I am, however, barely familiar with the subtleties of using `eval-and-compile` and, furthermore, do not expect this approach to be in any way superior.