# What effect does eval-and-compile have on a defun-within-let?

Tags: byte-compilation, lexical-scoping

The byte-compiler does not currently seem to recognise that a function has been defined when using `defun` within a `let` expression under `lexical-binding`, as explained in [Stefan's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29862/15748) to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29853/15748).

In my own initialisation file, I have found that I can make the `defun`-within-`let` obvious to the byte-compiler by wrapping the whole form in `eval-and-compile`, [as I noted under the same question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32622/15748).

My multipart question is:

1. What further effects (desirable or otherwise) does placing the `defun`-within-`let` within `eval-and-compile` have compared to the bare version w.r.t. interpretation/byte-compilation/macroexpansion, etc.
2. I roughly understand by looking at the definition of `defun` that it is a glorified wrapper around `defalias`. Apart from forgoing the explicit `(lambda () ...)` (or other function value) which needs to be passed to `defalias`, is there some other subtle difference between `defalias` and `defun`, e.g. different treatment by the byte-compiler?

Comment: A defun inside a let is not a toplevel defun.

Comment: @Drew I think I'm missing the correct meaning of a toplevel defun - could you please explain or point me to some documentation?

Comment: (emacs)[Defuns](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Defuns.html) and its descendant nodes come closest. Use `C-s top-level` in the manual to see more. A top-level sexp is just a sexp that is not enclosed in another sexp within a file or buffer (or perhaps some other scope of discourse).

Comment: @Drew Thanks for clarifying; I'll modify the question accordingly. One thing that searching through the manual did not clarify is whether the descendents of certain special forms (particularly `progn`) might still be considered "top-level" in some capacity, e.g. in the context of byte-compiler declarations, macro calls, etc.

Comment: If some such context treats a definition or other sexp specially, as if it were "top level", then that's not documented, as far as I know. Which generally means you should not depend on it, i.e., today's behavior might well not be respected tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

One bad side effect I discovered is when function's body itself also has `eval-and-compile` form (in addition to the outer one).  In particular, compared to the case when there is only `eval-and-compile` in function's body (and no outer one), after byte compiling a file with a target function and loading the byte compiled file, the call to the loaded function does not seem to yield evaluation of the function's body enclosed by `eval-and-compile`.

To be honest, I believe this is a bug like some others.  For example, nested `eval-and-compile` forms (without `defun` in the middle like in the case above) cause the innermost body to be evaluated twice but only at compile time, while `eval-when-compile` nested into `eval-and-compile` does not (surprise!) exhibit this issue.

The conclusion I arrived at, was to minimize the of use `eval-and-compile` and use it with care anyways to always be sure that nesting will/should not happen.