# Make a variable visible to some functions only

Tags: variables, byte-compilation, local-variables, lexical-scoping, defun

Consider the following metacode:

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defvar var1 ...)
(defvar var2 ...)

(defun main ()
  "Main entry point" ...)
(defun func1 ...)
(defun func2 ...)
...
(defun funcn ...)

(defun f ...)
(defun g ...)
```

If a variable is relevant to the whole logic of your program, you make it visible to all functions declaring it global in `defvar`. If a variable is relevant only to some functions, say `f` and `g` above, you make it visible to the latter functions only. This is known as [friendship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class), avoids "cluttering" the global space and can be easily implemented in elisp like follows:

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defun main ()
  "Main entry point"
  (message "f: %s; g: %s" (f) (g)))

(let ((x 0))
  (defun f () (1+ x))
  (defun g () (+ 2  x)))
```

Now `f` and `g` share the same variable `x` without using the global space, that is  without `(defvar x 0)`.

Unfortunately the compiler *wrongly* complains:

```
Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined: f, g
```

One can use without problems the byte-compiled code, but in so far as you want to use the compiler to lint your code,  false positives are not welcomed. Plus, the let-bound variable `x` becomes static.

I would like to find an alternative approach avoiding warnings and static variables.

### What I am not looking for

I am aware of this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29853/3975). Will Kunkel receives the same warning, however   he has a totally different objective: he "want(s) to get the effect of a static variable by using defun inside of let".

I have not one but several defuns and want to *share variables, not make them static*.

IMHO the proposed [let-bound variables in defalias](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29862/3975) are better avoided because calling twice the defalias function may cause an error difficult to spot as it does not stop your program, it just produces a biased output. Of course, this does not apply in specific cases when  you *explicitly need your function to keep its value between invocations*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defun inside let with lexical binding gives byte-compile warning "the function is not known to be defined"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29853/defun-inside-let-with-lexical-binding-gives-byte-compile-warning-the-function-i).

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The OP clearly knows that `f` and `g` are not local definitions. This question is about how to make the byte compiler aware of the fact that they have been defined by the time `g` is invoked in the call to `message`.

Comment: @Drew The OP in the proposed dup target is [also aware of that](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29853/defun-inside-let-with-lexical-binding-gives-byte-compile-warning-the-function-i#comment45862_29853), and that question is also about making the byte compiler aware of bound functions. On the other hand, having two functions sharing a let-binding won't work with Stefan's answer there, I think.

Comment: @npostavs: I guess they are more or less the same, as they both say they get the behavior they expect and they just want to know how to suppress the byte-compiler warnings.

Comment: @antonio after all your updates, I'm now much more confused as to what your question is.

Comment: @npostavs: Rewrote 4th time from scratch and summarising.

Comment: In `(let ((x 0)) (defun f ()...) (defun g ()...))` the `x` is every bit as "static" as in the `defalias` case. So it seems your question is still confused/confusing.

Comment: @npostavs: Why you say so? If I evaluate  `(f)`, `(g)`, or `(main)` twice I get the same result.

Comment: @antonio: You get the same result each time because none of your functions modify the value of `x`.

Comment: @phils: Oh yes, sorry, I was to fast too answer.  Then the your implied answer seems: there is no shared variable without a static one. Isn't it?

Comment: Again, there's only dynamic scope or lexical scope -- but I'm going to say "yes". In this example, `x` is only visible to a pair of function definitions `f` and `g` (there being no other code within that `let` body), so it is "shared" between the things which can see it, and it is "static" in that the variable exists (and persists) independently of calls to those functions. If you wanted a variable which was local to a single function and reset its value each time the function was called, you would have typically have a `let` within the function body.

Answer (score 3):

> `defalias` "magically" stores the variables inside its functions, so their values can be reused with subsequent calls.

This is not what `defalias` does; see [`(elisp) Defining Functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html). The means by which variables are "captured" in functions is called scoping and is specific to neither of `defun`, `defalias` or `fset`; see [`(elisp) Variable Scoping`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html).

> With `defalias` the variables are not actually shared, because the "owner" is the  `defalias` function.

I think what you mean is that, so long as either of them is nested within a `let`, a `defalias` makes the function definition no clearer to the byte-compiler than a `defun`. There are various mitigations for the byte-compiler warnings listed under the [linked question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29853/15748).

To capture local variables in functions, whether across a single function or multiple, you must enable [`lexical-binding`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html):

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(let ((greeting "hello"))
  (defun f ()
    (message "%s f" greeting))
  (defun g ()
    (message "%s g" greeting)))

(f)
(g)
```

The result is:

```
hello f
hello g
```

It doesn't matter whether you use `defun`, `defalias` or `fset` here - the result is always two closures `f` and `g` over the local variable `greeting`.

You can even modify the lexically bound variable:

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(let ((greeting "hello"))
  (defun f ()
    (setq greeting "goodbye")
    (message "%s f" greeting))
  (defun g ()
    (message "%s g" greeting)))

(g)
(f)
(g)
```

The result is:

```
hello g
goodbye f
goodbye g
```

So, as long as you're not forgetting to enable `lexical-binding`, I'm not sure what you mean by "static storage" and why that gives rise to wrong values / errors.

---

**Update**

> I would like to find an alternative approach avoiding warnings.

At the time of writing, the [linked question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29853/15748) showcases a couple of workarounds for the false byte-compiler warnings. In decreasing order of idiomaticity, simplicity, correctness, and elegance:

1. Use `declare-function` as [pointed out by Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/39454/15748). (Highly recommended!)
2. Wrap the whole form in `eval-and-compile` as [pointed out by yours truly](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32622/15748). (Your friends may laugh at you unless you know the precise reason for doing this, and friends are known to laugh regardless.)

The reason replacing `(let ((...)) (defun ...))` with `(defalias ... (let ((...)) (lambda ...)))`, as [suggested by Stefan](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29862/15748), doesn't work in your case is because sharing a lexical variable across multiple closures still requires a top-level `let` (as opposed to top-level `defalias` or `defun`), thus confusing the byte-compiler.

> I am aware of this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29853/3975). Will Kunkel receives the same warning, however   he has a totally different objective: he "want(s) to get the effect of a static variable by using defun inside of let".

The objective of Will Kunkel's code is irrelevant; the linked question is about silencing the same false byte-compiler that you are seeing, whose cause is a non-top-level function definition, i.e. a function definition obfuscated by a surrounding `let` form.

> IMHO the proposed [let-bound variables in defalias](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29862/3975) are better avoided. Calling twice the defalias function may cause an error difficult to spot as it does not stop your program, it just produces a biased output.

I see neither reason to avoid the suggested closure, nor why it should give rise to errors, nor what you mean by "biased output". It sounds like you have misunderstood how `lexical-binding` and/or `defalias` work and are possibly misusing them. Keep in mind that `defun` is merely a wrapper around `defalias`.

Comment: @phils Thanks, I've tried to clarify. The original intent was to address OP's question, not emphasise the multiple functions.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the missing lexical bindings. It was kind of implicit in my snippets, but it could cause misunderstandings, so I updated again, explaining the unclear parts too. As regards your solution, say I have 20 functions with global variables shared through `defvar` and "occasional" variables shared just by a couple of functions. Isolating the latter in a single `let` seemed (also visually) a good idea, but the compiler wrongly complains. Adding lexical binding has no effect on compiler warnings.

Comment: @antonio `lexical-binding` has nothing to do with compiler warnings and everything to do with scoping. You cannot create closures without `lexical-binding`. The reason `defalias` suppresses warnings in the linked question is because it is at the top-level, whereas a `defun` within a `let` is not at the top-level. Please see the [linked question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29853/15748) for ways of suppressing byte-compiler warnings pertaining to non-top-level function definitions.

Comment: @antonio In your updated question, you seem to be conflating concepts from other programming languages with Elisp. Please read the suggested [`(elisp) Variable Scoping`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html) and [`(elisp) Variables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variables.html) more generally to understand how variable definitions and scoping work in Elisp. I also fail to see how your updated question has anything to do with its original title, so please consider opening a new, more focussed question.

Comment: @Because "Making a variable visible to some functions only" is a feature that exists in C++ (known to many).  Theoretical discussions apart, your snippets still give me the compiler warnings. Btw, there is 4th rewrite.

Comment: @antonio As has already been pointed out to you, the linked question already tells you how to silence the byte-compiler. As my answer already explains, the snippets showcase `lexical-binding`, not how to silence the byte-compiler. See my updated answer.