# flycheck "function is not known to be defined" warning after conditional definition

Tags: flycheck

I was running into a flycheck warning about a function which may not be defined.

Since the function is a small optional dependency, I am inlining it in case the package that provides cannot be loaded.

I first tried I checking if the package failed to be required before filling in the function:

```
(unless (require 'selcand nil t)
  (defun selcand-select () ...))
```

This gave me

```
the function ‘selcand-select’ is not known to be defined.
```

Which makes sense since the compiler has no idea whether the `selcand package`
will define the function `selcand-select`.

So I added an explicit `fboundp` check:

```
(unless (and (require 'selcand nil t) (fboundp 'selcand-select))
  (defun selcand-select (cands &optional prompt stringify) ...))
```

which still gave me the same error.

Comment: Similar to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29853/defun-inside-let-with-lexical-binding-gives-byte-compile-warning-the-function-i

Answer (score 1):

What did silence the warning was making the condition simpler for the compiler:

```
(require 'selcand nil t) 
(unless (fboundp 'selcand-select)
    (defun selcand-select (cands &optional prompt stringify) ...))
```

Interestingly the following also works:

```
(require 'selcand nil t) 
(unless (and (require 'selcand nil t) (fboundp 'selcand-select))
    (defun selcand-select (cands &optional prompt stringify) ...))
```

Earlier I had also tried wrapping the form in 'eval-when-compile:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (unless (require 'selcand nil t)
    (defun selcand-select () ...)))
```

which failed with:

```
the function ‘selcand-select’ might not be defined at runtime.
```

This also makes sense for the same reason that my first approach didn't work, and
`eval-when-compile` is not needed here since `selcand-select` is not a macro.